# Column background image

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, columns, backgrounds

I have a two column frame (via wiki2beamer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Background Test}

\begin{columns}

    \column{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Left Column 1
        \item Left Column 2
    \end{itemize}

    \column{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Right Column 1
        \item Right Column 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to put a background image on one column. I've tried and failed with CTAN `adjustbox`, `background` & `wallpaper`. I'm shocked that `usebackgroundtemplate` appears to bind only to the page and has no other scope -- unless I'm mistaken (I'm new to LaTeX). Ideally, I'd like the background image to work with `\uncover` and `\only`.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert an image in the background using the standard `\includegraphics` command, supplemented by a `\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]` to remove any vertical height/displacement.

The following minimal working example does exactly that, with the addition of any of the regular `beamer` overlay specification functionality:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background Test}

  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.3\textwidth}
      \only<2>{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{tiger}}}%
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Left Column 1
        \item Left Column 2
      \end{itemize}

    \column{0.7\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Right Column 1
        \item Right Column 2
      \end{itemize}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've set the width of the image to be exactly `\linewidth`, which is the width of the column that it is put in (the first). The height of the image is set to `4cm`, but you can modify this as needed.

Of course there are other methods (using other packages), but this seems to be the most straight forward, since it uses the only the essential [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), actually already included by [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

Comment: Werner, the `\raisebox` macro already boxes the content. You can simply say `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[..]{..}}`. You can also set the effective height and depth using two optional arguments after the first mandatory one: `\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[..]{..}}`. Then you don't need `\smash`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Today I learned something new, thanks! The results weren't the same though, with `\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{...}` causing a vertical shift in the other content. Same goes for `\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{...}}`. Any idea why?

Comment: I get the exact same results for all three. I used the following code for comparison which didn't showed any difference on slides 2-4: `\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{tiger}}%
      \only<2>{\smash{\raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}}}%
      \only<3>{\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{tiger}}}}%
      \only<4>{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{tiger}}}%`

Comment: @MartinScharrer: You're right. I must have had a spurious space in there somewhere. Thanks again.